# Dividing an array into separate arrays of four elements plus the reminder

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to divide an array into individual arrays of four elements, where the last array will contain the reminder. For example, if that main array's length property will be ten, three subarrays will be created - two consisting of four elements, and one of two elements.

The code I have right now looks like the following:

```
NSMutableArray *mainMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", @"Fourth", @"Fifth", @"Sixth", @"Seventh", @"Eighth", nil];
NSMutableArray *mutableArrayOfSubarrays = [NSMutableArray array];

int length = mainMutableArray.count / 4;
int location = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    [mutableArrayOfSubarrays addObject:[mainMutableArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(location, 4)]];
    location += 4;
}
```

This of course works only when the reminder is equal to 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what result are you getting with that and what is your actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here we go:

```
int length = mainMutableArray.count;

for (int location = 0; location < length; location+=4)
{
    unsigned int Size=length-location;
    if (Size>4) Size=4;
    [mutableArrayOfSubarrays addObject:[mainMutableArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(location, Size)]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `while` loop, you can make the condition describe what you are actually trying to do:

```
NSUInteger length = [mainMutableArray count];
NSUInteger location = 0;
// Until the location is less than four away from the end
while( location <= (length - 4) ){

    [mutableArrayOfSubarrays addObject:[mainMutableArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(location, 4)]];
    location += 4;
}

// Pick up the remainder, if any
if( location != length ){
    [mutableArrayOfSubarrays addObject:[mainMutableArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(location, length-location)]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop from `length*4` to `mainMutableArray.count` to get the remainder of the array.